# Remove properties that have empty array as its value?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have this object and I'm trying to do the following:

1) Remove properties that have an empty array as its value.

2) If the value of a property is an array that has only 1 element, then set the value to that element instead of an array.

Example:

```
colors: ['blue']
```

then just set it to

```
colors: 'blue'
```

So far I have this code that only removes the properties which values are null

```
var obj = {name: 'John', lastname: 'Smith', colores: ['blue'], movies: [], age: 20, country: null};

var result = _.pickBy(obj);
console.log(result); // {name: "John", lastname: "Smith", colores: Array(1), movies: Array(0), age: 20}
```

How to get it to work so it returns this:

```
{name: "John", lastname: "Smith", colores: 'blue', age: 20}
```

Comment: _If the value of a property is an array that has 1 element.._ Then what?

Comment: @hindmost then set it to that value: Example if colors: ['blue'] then just set it to just colors: 'blue'

Comment: @hindmost it's in the question :)

Comment: it's easier to process `([], [x], [x1,x2,x3,...])` than it is to process `(undefined, x, [x1,x2,x3,...])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `_.transform()` to change the object's values, and remove keys:

```js
var obj = {name: 'John', lastname: 'Smith', colores: ['blue'], movies: [], age: 20, country: null};

var result = _.transform(obj, (acc, v, k) => {
  if(_.isNil(v) || _.isObject(v) && _.isEmpty(v)) return;
  
  if(_.isArray(v) && _.eq(v.length, 1)) acc[k] = _.head(v);
  else acc[k] = v;
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`_.omitBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#omitBy) and [`_.mapValues`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#mapValues):

```js
let obj = { name: 'John', lastname: 'Smith', colores: ['blue'], movies: [], age: 20, country: null }; 

let result = _.omitBy(obj, x => _.isEmpty(x) && !_.isNumber(x))
result = _.mapValues(result, x => _.isArray(x) && !_.isEmpty(x) ? _.first(x) : x)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

With chaining:

```js
let obj = { name: 'John', lastname: 'Smith', colores: ['blue'], movies: [], age: 20, country: null };

let result = _(obj)
  .omitBy(x => _.isEmpty(x) && !_.isNumber(x))
  .mapValues(x => _.isArray(x) && x.length == 1 ? _.first(x) : x)
  .value()

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```